# Defining variables with \def and using them in PS calculations in PSTricks context unexpected behaviour

Tags: pstricks

I find the documentation and examples for using PSTricks do not help me with the following problem:   define (using `\def` OR `\edef`?) `thetai=80`, `thetaii=220`, `thetaiii=285`. Then compute (using `\def` OR `\edef`) `bet=180+thetai`, `alph=thetai+thetaii`, `gam=bet - alph`.

Now `\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){2.0}{0}{\X}` only works for angles `bet` and `alph` NOT `gam ()`

```
PS->DVI produces

Process started

Error: /undefined

in !

Operand stack: angleB Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1910 1 3 %oparray_pop 1909 1 3 %oparray_pop 1893 1 3 %oparray_pop 1787 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1164/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:123/200(L)-- --dict:175/300(L)-- --dict:38/200(L)-- --dict:100/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: 2 Current file position is 128390 GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

Example code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{pst-math}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}   

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{pspicture}
[showgrid=false](-5,-5)(5,5)

\def\r{4 }
\pnode(0,0){origin}
\pscircle(origin){\r}

\def\thetai{80.0 }
\def\XYi{!\thetai cos \r mul \thetai sin \r mul }
\pnode(\XYi){ni}
\qline(origin)(ni)

\def\thetaii{220.0 }
\def\XYii{! \thetaii cos \r mul \thetaii sin \r mul }
\pnode(\XYii){nii}
\qline(origin)(nii)

\def\thetaiii{285.0 }
\def\XYiii{! \thetaiii cos \r mul \thetaiii sin \r mul }
\pnode(\XYiii){niii}
\qline(origin)(niii)
\thetaiii 

\psline(ni)(nii)(niii)(ni)

\def\bet{!180.0 \thetai add }
\bet
\def\alph{! \thetai\space \thetaii\space add }
\alph 
\edef\gam{! \bet\space \alph\space  sub }
\gam 


\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){2.0}{0}{\alph}
\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){1.5}{0}{\bet}
\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){1.5}{0}{\gam}

\end{pspicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For angles use it this way:

```
\def\bet{ 180.0 \thetai add }
\def\alph{ \thetai\space \thetaii\space add } 
\edef\gam{ \bet\space \alph\space  sub }

\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){2.0}{0}{!\alph}
\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){1.5}{0}{!\bet}
\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){1.5}{0}{!\gam}
```

Otherwise the `!` cannot be extracted by PSTricks. This happens only for angles which can be defined in several ways.

The complete working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}   
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\def\r{4 }
\pnode(0,0){origin}
\pscircle(origin){\r}

\def\thetai{80.0 }
\def\XYi{!\thetai cos \r mul \thetai sin \r mul }
\pnode(\XYi){ni}
\qline(origin)(ni)

\def\thetaii{220.0 }
\def\XYii{! \thetaii cos \r mul \thetaii sin \r mul }
\pnode(\XYii){nii}
\qline(origin)(nii)

\def\thetaiii{285.0 }
\def\XYiii{! \thetaiii cos \r mul \thetaiii sin \r mul }
\pnode(\XYiii){niii}
\qline(origin)(niii)

\psline(ni)(nii)(niii)(ni)

\def\bet{ 180.0 \thetai add }
\def\alph{ \thetai\space \thetaii\space add } 
\edef\gam{ \bet\space \alph\space  sub }

\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){2.0}{0}{!\alph}
\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){1.5}{0}{!\bet}
\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){1.5}{0}{!\gam}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but no sir! I already tried this. Note that works for \alpha and \bet but not \gam

Comment: Oh! I see the lost ! in the \defs, this now works!

Answer (score 0):

I love refactoring.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\pstVerb
{
    /radius 4 def
    /thetai 80 def
    /thetaii 220 def
    /thetaiii 285 def
    /alpha {thetai thetaii add} def
    /beta {180 thetai add} def
    /gamma {beta alpha sub} def
}   
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,6)
\pnodes
    (0,0){origin}
    (!radius thetai PtoC){ni}
    (!radius thetaii PtoC){nii}
    (!radius thetaiii PtoC){niii}

\pscircle(origin){!radius}
\qline(origin)(ni)
\qline(origin)(nii)
\qline(origin)(niii)

\pspolygon(ni)(nii)(niii)

\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){2.0}{0}{!alpha}
\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){1.5}{0}{!beta}
\psarc[linestyle=dotted](ni){1.5}{0}{!gamma}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]